# Flask Server Post Not Working On Heroku

Tags: python, api, heroku, flask

I tested my code locally and it worked just fine. However, pushing it to heroku didn't go so well. First off, I have this base Root API to check that my heroku config is fine:

```
class Root(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"works": "fine"}
api.add_resource(Root, "/")
```

Indeed this gets me the correct object when I visit my website. Here's my real endpoint that I want for my webapp:

```
class Update(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def post(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form["data"]
        return {"name": "A", "uv": "4000", "pv": todos[todo_id], "amt": "2400"}


def add_data():
    global hist_data
    while True:
        _position = _status()
        hist_data += [{"name": "price", "uv": 4000, "pv": _position, "amt": 2400}]
        jsonized = json.dumps(hist_data)
        post("https://myflaskapi1.herokuapp.com/history", data={"data": jsonized}).json()
        sleep(600)
```

`api.add_resource(Update, "/<string:todo_id>")`

And this is how I loop the add_data() post request:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=add_data)
    p.start()
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port, use_reloader=False)
    p.join()
```

Now, locally this worked just fine, I was able to post a request and then go to localhost:5000/history to get the object. On Heroku, I get: `{"message": "Internal Server Error"}`
I tried sending a post request with Postman too and here is what I got:

```
{
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

Context: I'm collecting data so that it is rendered later by a React Chart component. Hence, I'm looping the add_data() function to accrue more data every 600 seconds.

Comment: What is your Procfile? There is no way to solve this problem without knowing it's contents.

Comment: @Fian now it is `web: gunicorn app:app` but I had set it to `web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app` and it didn't work.

Comment: 1. For `Internal Server Error` see heroku logs to find it's cause, stackoverflow can't and won't do it for you. 2. For `The browser (or proxy) sent a request...` it indicates that you are making a request in a wrong way and it's pretty easy to solve using google. You have many unrelated errors, I think best approach would be to create as simple as possible but working Heroku flask application (not locally) like 1 handler returning 200 OK and then add features. With this approach errors would be isolated and quite salvageable for you.